# Php won't show requested data from database (sql)

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to display all the movies with specific hashtag.

The results are not showing but there are no errors.

However i should get movie poster image and title as result. :/

In my database, this is 'tags' row of one movie

```
#watchonline #movies-with-subs #hdmovies
```

and tag.php

```
<?php
require "db.inc.php";

if (isset($_GET['tag'])) {
$tag = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_-]#i', '', $_GET["tag"]);
$fulltag = "#" . $tag;
echo $fulltag;
$ASDsql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE tags LIKE '$fulltag' OR tags = 
'$fulltag'";
$tagQuery = mysqli_query($db, $ASDsql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($tagQuery);
if($count > 0) {
while ($hastags = mysqli_fetch_array($tagQuery)) {
$id = $hastags['id'];

$movie_title = $hastags['movie_title'];

$movie_url = $hastags['movie_url'];

$movie_image = $hastags['movie_image'];


$movie_identity = $hastags['movie_identity'];

echo "<div class='item'><a href='movie.php?movie=$id'><img 
src='$movie_image'><p>$movie_title</p></a></div>";
}
}else {
echo "No movies under that tag";
}
}
?>
```

I've checked db.inc.php file it's all good.
My output is "No movies under that tag";
*Im sorry if this is a copy i really looked and could not find an answer*

Comment: You need to explain what the error is, what the output is and the expected result.

Comment: I don't get any error, only the output "No movies udner that tag"

Comment: `LIKE` usually requires a `%` or `_`, like so: `...where tags like '%test%'`

Comment: Tried still same thing.

Comment: Try `var_dump($tagQuery);` This will let you see what is being returned from the Query

Comment: I get bool(false) when i do that.

Comment: Okay; so you are not receiving anything from your database. That means your `LIKE` statement is not finding anything on the table's row. What is your table structure?

Comment: Got it working thank you all :)
LIKE statement was not needed

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 $ASDsql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE tags LIKE '%$fulltag%' OR tags = 
'%$fulltag%'";
```

or may be the table is not having any value

Comment: It worked. It seem "LIKE" was not necessary at all.
The working output is  $ASDsql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE tags = 
'%$fulltag%'";

Comment: does your column tags have value starting with "%"  since you are equating with that

Comment: No they are like this #tag. however i have litle function that convert any hashtag string (#string) into clickable link

Comment: how can you get the result by condition ```where tags='%$fulltag%'``` ,since this contain a character ```%``` in the start hence the condition will match with ```%```  not with ```#``` and you are also not using like query.